# Row elements validation in Coded UI

Tags: asp.net, validation, coded-ui-tests

I am working on **Coded UI** for an `asp.net` web application.

In one of tests I need to **validate and verify if the elements of the row are populated right or not.** 
For instance, suppose my search criteria is such that the `Serial Number` should start from `001`. As soon as I click on Search button my results grid gets populated with all the elements that have `001` in there serial number.

How can I validate that all the elements of the results grid are correct i.e. starting from `001`? I know I must use `.contains` validation criteria.

**But what code should I use to run the loop for checking each and every row?** in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is heavily dependent upon what you mean by **`populated right`**

Is your grid rendering/CodedUI-Defined as a `HtmlTable`?

If your grid has strict columns you could just ask for the cells matching your criteria.

```
var cellDef = new HtmlCell(yourHtmlTable);
cellDef.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex, "2");
cellDef.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.InnerText, "YourDynamicValue", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
var matchingCells = cellDef.FindMatchingControls().OfType<HtmlCell>().ToArray();
```

Assuming your list is somewhat dynamic then you could just validate each entry exists. If you are trying to validate **EVERY** row, its contents, and formatting. If so you'll just have to cycle every row and ask for each cell according to your criteria.

```
foreach(HtmlRow row in yourTable.Rows)
{
   var idCell = row.GetCell(0);
   var decriptionCell = row.GetCell(1);
   // your code to match your entries
}
```